# Como não inserir dados na base de dados com mysqli e php?

Tags: php, mysqli

Eu gostaria de saber se alguém me pode ajudar é que eu não quero inserir na base de dados valores em que o titulo é igual mas não estou conseguindo.
Com o código abaixo ele insere sempre na base de dados, não esse filtro de não permitir inserir dados com o mesmo titulo na base de dados. 
Nota: tenho que usar obrigatoriamente mysqli.
Obrigado.

```
function inserirNaTabelaFilmesRegisto(
        $db, //ponteiro pelo qual se faz o acesso à SGBDR
        $titulo, $urlImagem, $hrefAssistir, $categoria, $classificacao
    )
    {

//var_dump($db);
//$db = estabelecerLigacaoSGBDR();
if ($db!==false){
    $select = "select * from  filme where titulo = '$titulo'";
    if($result = $db->query($select)===true) {
 echo "ERRO!<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>";
    }else{
    $q = "insert into ".BD.".".TABELA_FILME;
           $q.=" values (null, '$titulo', '$urlImagem', '$hrefAssistir', '$categoria', '$classificacao');";
    $db->query($q);
    $e = mysqli_errno($db);
    $eM = mysqli_error($db);
    echo $eM;
    if ($e===0){
        return true;
    }
    }
}//if
return false;
}//inserirNaTabelaApontamentosRegisto
```

Comment: Dê  UNIQUE na coluna, isso irá previnir uma informação duplicada

Comment: Você pode projetar devidamente o banco de dados e definir a coluna como única, não precisando fazer código para isso.

Comment: Resultou @Inkeliz e @AndersonCarlosWoss! Muito obrigado. Deus vos Abençoe.

Comment: Talvez ajude colocando como único no banco ou fazendo uma consulta ao banco e verificar se já existe.

Comment: Neste link: http://blog.thiagobelem.net/guia-pratico-de-mysqli-no-php ensina como fazer uma consulta do tipo SELECT com mysqli, quando pegar o dado compara com o qual deseja verificar se já existe.

Comment: Obrigado @Henrique Buzin pela informação.